# Linux Mint 19.1 BETA service management?

Tags: linux-mint, services

How to figure which system Linux Mint 19.1 BETA is? `sysv`? `upstart`?

And how to manage i.e. enable/disable services, start/stop?

I had problems with 17.3 because it was using both and couldn't manage the services.

Now I switched to 19.1 and want to figure it once and for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop a service:

```
sudo service NAME stop
```

To start a service:

```
sudo service NAME start
```

To disable a service:

```
sudo systemctl disable NAME
```

To enable a service:

```
sudo systemctl enable NAME
```

---

There are always more ways around. I showed you just what you asked for in one possible way.

---

Note: Linux Mint 19.x is based on Ubuntu 18.04, so you can use your favorite search engine to find more information.

Comment: I'd recommand the `systemctl start [service name]` instead of the old service command which will probably be deprecated as systemd is taking over the linux world